# middlewares not running in Express

Tags: node.js, express

Based on Express docs, a middleware must run each time app is launched following this code:

```
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Time:', Date.now());
    next();
});
```

Well, trying to execute with the most simple possilbe example middleware never is excuted:

```
var express = require('express');
var middleware = require('./middleware');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next){
    console.log('MIDDLEWARE');
    next();
});

module.exports = app;
```

Middleware never runs.

Also tryed to make it working from a separated file, but never runs.

Thanks

Comment: this is probably an issue with versions. express syntax has changed a fair bit recently. make sure the code you are using is relevant for the version of express you are using. also, make sure that the code is actually being hit.  for example, if you console.log directly after var app = express(); does the log statement show?

Answer (score 1):

Middleware are lunch when there are any request to the server.

Create a route and send a request to that, the middleware would be lunched.

Comment: Correct, they are only executed when a request is being processed and the a response hasn't been sent yet within the chain. If you want to run something on startup you can use an event listener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ups, seems to be they're launched when recieves a request. So using Postman it worked.